# Can't click on SQL Profiler

Tags: freeze, sql-server

I used to be able to launch SQL Profiler from SSMS with no problem, but now when the application starts I can't click on anything. It just *dings* at me. It's almost like there's a dialog open off screen that needs to be closed. I can't even start a trace. Has anyone experienced this? How can I fix it? I'm using 2014.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No sooner did I post this question did I figure out an answer. It was the "Connect to Server" dialog that was opening off screen. Hitting the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key closed the dialog and allowed me to continue.